# How to get username, userid... inside a iframe from PrestaShop

Tags: php, forms, iframe, prestashop

I'm trying to do a search box in a php file, which I need to integrate inside a page of prestashop. I do a form in the php file, and I need to send the userid and username of the logged user from prestashop, but I don't know how, because the php is not a part of prestashop, it is only included in a iframe of a page.

Comment: And so far you've tried, what?

Comment: I have a form in a php file, in which one of the params will be the username and the userid, of the logged user in prestashop. But I don't know how to achieve this part, it will be something like: $userid = "something?"

Comment: It is only possible if the source of the iframe is on the same domain as the prestashop.